# How to enable tab completion in sftp like Centos7 on Slackware?

Tags: ssh, sftp

On Centos7(and 6,5,and suse..)
i see sftp has tab completion,like "readline" function,like bash.
This not happen in Slackware,i have tried to recompile ssh

```
"with-readline"
"enable-readline"
```

but nothing change.
Any solution?
Please not answer "alias sftp=with-readline sftp" because is awful and centos not using it.

Comment: Did you compile ssh with libedit?

Comment: Not sure if it would work for sftp/ssh or not, but you could `yum install bash-completion` from the EPEL repo (`yum install epel-release`). This is what I did to get bash-style completion for yum itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CentOS/RHEL/Fedora is using openssh compiled with [`libedit`](http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/cgit/openssh.git/tree/openssh.spec#n585), which has its problems, but does its job for basic use cases. You just need to pass

```
--with-libedit
```

to `configure` when you are building `openssh` from source.